# Read digits from an int and counting them

Tags: c++, boolean

Alright so I've been looking though Google and on forums for hours and can't seem to understand how to solve this problem.

I need to write a program that first determines if the number entered by the user is a base 5 number (in other words, a number that only has 0s, 1s, 2s, 3s, and 4s in it). Then, I have to count how many 0s, 1s, 2s, etc are in the number and display it to the user.

I've seen people saying I should convert `int` to a `string` and then using `cin.get()`.
I noticed that I can't use `cin.get()` on a `string`, it needs to be a `char`.

I can only use a `while` loop for this assignment, no `while... do` loops.

Any help is appreciated!!

Here's what I have so far, obviously with all my mistakes in it:

```
//----------------------------------------------
// Assignment 3
// Question 1
// File name: q1.cpp
// Written by: Shawn Rousseau (ID: 7518455)
// For COMP 218 Section EC / Winter 2015
// Concordia University, Montreal, QC
//-----------------------------------------------

// The purpose of this program is to check if the 
// number entered by the user is a base of 5
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  // Declaring variables
  int number;
  int zeros;
  int ones;
  int twos;
  int threes;
  int fours;
  bool base5;

  // Get data and calculate

  cin >> number;
  string numberString = to_string(number);

  // Determine if the number is a base 5 number
  while (cin.get(numberString) == 0 || cin.get(numberString) == 1 ||
    cin.get(numberString) == 2 || cin.get(numberString) == 3 || 
    cin.get(numberString) == 4)
    base5 = true;


  // Determine the number of each digits
  zeros = 0;
  ones = 0;
  twos = 0;
  threes = 0;
  fours = 0;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Btw, as you can see, I'm a beginner. This is C++

Answer (score 0):

Several things you need to beware of:

One way to get a specific character from a `std::string` is by `[]`.  e.g.

```
std::string myString{"abcdefg"};
char myChar = myString[4];  // myChar == 'e'
```

`cin.get(aString)` is not trying to get data from `aString`.  It continues to get data from stdin and store in aString.  Once you have get the data and put into the string, you can simply manipulate the string itself.

a short piece of code that will count number of vowel in a string.  If you can understand it, there should be no problem doing your work.  (Haven't compiled, probably some typos)

```
std::string inputString;
std::cin >> inputString;

// you said you need a while loop.
// although it is easier to with for loop and iterator...
int i = 0;
int noOfVowels = 0;
while (i < inputString.length()) {
    if (inputString[i] == 'a' 
          || inputString[i] == 'e' 
          || inputString[i] == 'i' 
          || inputString[i] == 'o' 
          || inputString[i] == 'u' ) {
        ++noOfVowels;
    }

    ++i;
}
std::cout << "number of vowels : " << noOfVowels << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this approach. This will solve your needs I guess.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int number=0;
    int zeros=0;
    int ones=0;
    int twos=0;
    int threes=0;
    int fours=0;
    bool valid=true;;
    int counter = 0;



    cout<<"Enter the number: ";
    cin >> number;
    stringstream out;
    out << number; //int to string
    string numberString = out.str();
    cout<<"\n\nNumber after string conversion : "<<numberString;
    cout<<"\nPrinting this just to show that the conversion was successful\n\n\n";




    while (counter < numberString.length()) 
    {
        if (numberString[counter] == '0')
            zeros++;
        else if(numberString[counter] == '1')
            ones++;
        else if(numberString[counter] == '2')
            twos++;
        else if(numberString[counter] == '3')
            threes++;
        else if(numberString[counter] == '4')
            fours++;
        else
            valid=false;
        counter++;
     }

        if(valid==true)
        {
            cout<<"\nZeros : "<<zeros;
            cout<<"\nOnes : "<<ones;
            cout<<"\nTwos : "<<twos;
            cout<<"\nThrees : "<<threes;
            cout<<"\nFours : "<<fours;
        }
        else
            cout<<"\n\nInvalid data...base of 5 rule violated";


    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use std::string then use characters, first loop over the input from the user until ENTER is pressed.

```
char ch = 0;
while ((ch = cin.get()) != '\n')
{
...
}
```

For each character read, check if it is a digit (std::isdigit) and if it is in the range 0..4, if not quit and give some message of not being base 5

have an array of ints to keep track of the frequency of the digits

```
int freq[5] = {0,0,0,0,0};
```

after you have checked that the character is valid subtract the ascii value from the digit and use that as index in the array, increment that:

```
freq[ch - '0']++;
```

e.g.

```
char ch;
int freq[5] = {0};
while ((ch = cin.get()) != '\n')
{
  cout << ch;
  freq[ch-'0']++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(freq)/sizeof(freq[0]); ++i)
{
  cout << static_cast<char>(48+i) << ":" << freq[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useful function that counts digits:

```
// D returns the number of times 'd' appears as a digit of n.
// May not work for n = INT_MIN.
int D(int n, int d) {
    // Special case if we're counting zeros of 0.
    if (n == 0 && d == 0) return 1;
    if (n < 0) n = -n;
    int r = 0;
    while (n) {
        if (n % 10 == d) r++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return r;
}
```

In your code you can use this naively to solve the problem without any further loops.

```
if (D(n, 5) + D(n, 6) + D(n, 7) + D(n, 8) + D(n, 9) != 0) {
    cout << "the number doesn't consist only of the digits 0..4."
}
cout << "0s: " << D(n, 0) << "\n";
cout << "1s: " << D(n, 1) << "\n";
cout << "2s: " << D(n, 2) << "\n";
cout << "3s: " << D(n, 3) << "\n";
cout << "4s: " << D(n, 4) << "\n";
```

You could also (or should also) use loops here to reduce the redundancy.

Comment: I seem to have solved all of my issues, except I get LNK2019 (unresolved external symbol) and LNK1120. Am I missing a library to use the D (base 5) function?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: the code for D is in the answer.